# How can i get information from object- Java? Can I simplify my code more?

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor

I was assigned a project to create a class, and use methods without editing the "EmployeeTester" class. How can i get the name from the object harry instead of setting name ="harry"? And also can I simplify my code more?

```
public class EmployeeTester
    {
        /**
         * main() method
         */
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Employee harry = new Employee("Hacker, Harry", 50000.0);**\\
            harry.raiseSalary(25.0);    // Harry gets a 25 percent raise!

            System.out.println(harry.getName() + " now makes " +
                                                      harry.getSalary());
        }

    }



public class Employee
{
    // instance variables 
    private double salary;
    private String name;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Employee
     */
    public Employee(String employeeName, double currentSalary)
    {
        //Initializes instance variables
        salary = currentSalary;
        name = employeeName;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        //Sets name to harry
        name = "Harry";
        return name;
    }
        public void raiseSalary(double byPercent)
    {
        //multiplies by 1.25 percent to get the 25% raise
        salary = salary *(1 + byPercent/100);
        return;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        //returns the salary
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask youself these questions: what is the use of a constructor. What is the role of the argument employeeName? What does the line `name = employeeName;`do? When I ask an employee his/her name, should that automatically change his/her name to "harry"? Why does a method named `getName`has, as its first comment `Sets name to harry`. Are "get" and "set" synonyms?

Comment: In the constructor you already set `name = employeeName`, in the `getName` method why would you **set** the `name` to harry? The method is supposed to tell you what the name is, not to change the name, right?

Also, you don't need the `return` in `raiseSalary`, it is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It can be like this

```
class Employee
{
   private double salary;
   private String name;

   public Employee(String titleName, double salary) {
    this.name = titleName.split(",")[1];
    this.salary =salary;
   }

   public void raiseSalary(double byPercent) {
      salary = salary *(1 + byPercent/100);
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public double getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
}
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like this. According to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), you should only pass the necessary information in: so the constructor's `String titleName` parameter should simply be `String name`; then there's no need to munge it in the constructor. Let callers work out how best to pass in the name; minimize the knowledge that the `Employee` class needs.